# Can NUnit console runner pass some command line arguments to nunit-agent?

Tags: nunit

We use the NUnit console to run our tests in Jenkins and we have many projects that share some tests. We want to be able to run the tests concurrently and to do that we need the tests to look at different databases.

I would like to pass in the project name to the `nunit-agent` which wouldn't know how to use it, but we would be able to fetch that from the command line arguments running the test and decide which database to look at.

I am open to suggestions.

We currently use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" Path\Tests.dll --result=nunit-result1.xml` to run the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nunit-agent uses arguments to pass information that NUnit needs. For passing information to the test, the standard way is to use the `--params` command-line option and then access the values from your tests by means of `TestContext.Parameters`.